# Using jQuery getJSON and fire a function AFTER the results have been processed... should work... but doesn't

Tags: javascript, function, getjson, jquery

I have a series of functions which populate a series of drop down boxes.

This is a product data page, and serves both to add a new item, or edit an existing one. In the latter case, once all the drop down boxes are populated, it grabs an item data from a database as a JSON string and selects the appropriate values in the drop down bozes using `$('#elem').val('value')`

This all works fine, except I can't get it to things in the right order.

```
1.  function loadBrands() {
2.     $('#brand').empty().append('<option value="">Select...</option>').addClass('centreLoader');
3.     $.getJSON('/jsonData/brands.txt', function (data) {
4.         $.each(data, function (i, item) {
5.             $('#brand').append('<option value="' + data[i].label + '">' + data[i].brandName+ '</option>');
6.         });
7.         $('#brand').removeClass('centreLoader');
8.         loadSavedItem(); 
9.     });
10. };
```

I've added line numbers to explain simply (although you'll all know what this does!)

Line 3 gets the JSON data from my file (this is valid data as it populates fine), then line 4 begins looping the data returned and populating the drop down.

Line 8 is where things go wrong, this calls the function `loadSavedItem` which looks a bit like this:

```
1.  function loadSavedItem(thisItemId) {
2.     $.getJSON('/jsonData/QUERY_DB_FOR_THIS_PRODUCT (thisItemId)', function (data) {
3.         $('#brand').val(data[0].brand);
4.     });
5.  };
```

Again, pretty simple, line 2 gets the JSON output (which is again valid, it populates other fields fine) and sets the field values as applicable (this is obviously a shortened version of the code)

The problem appears to be that `loadSavedItem()` is being called too soon, before `#brands` is fully populated, so it cannot set the value correctly. If I put a time delay in, then it works.

BUT... I thought that anything after the `$(each...` jQuery statement should not happen until `$(each)` has finished?

How can I ensure that this is the case?

Comment: `label` and `brandName` are your value/display properties?  Then in your 2nd request, you use `brand` to set your value - I'm guessing this corresponds to `label` since you said this works after a short delay.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The data sources are different in each JSON call so therefore the label names are too, but yes, in example 1, the drop down is populated with a `label` value, the output of the second example gives `brand` as the value to select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, $(each) can loop while the rest of the script is running, if that makes sense (in Chrome, at least). Maybe it's something to do with "optimisation".

I've solved this problem before by checking `data.length`, setting a counter that increments by one and then firing the code off if the counter equals the length.

```
function loadBrands() {
    $('#brand').empty().append('<option value="">Select...</option>').addClass('centreLoader');
    $.getJSON('/jsonData/brands.txt', function (data) {
        var dataNum = data.length;
        var counter = 1;
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('#brand').append('<option value="' + data[i].label + '">' + data[i].brandName+ '</option>');
            if (dataNum == counter) {
                $('#brand').removeClass('centreLoader');
                loadSavedItem(); 
            }
            counter ++;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Really? OK, everything I've read online says that it should wait until completing before the next command is processed, but, the results I am getting suggest you're right. I'll try adding a counter. You'd suggest an `if` statement within the loop that triggers the function when `counter == data.length` I assume?

Comment: Yup - I edited some code into my answer to help people who visit this page in the future. And I agree - JS is meant to be single-threaded, but that's certainly doesn't seem to always be the case.

Comment: Oh! You've added an example! Excellent

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add the method "loadSavedItem()" in the Success function something like below. This should solve the problem.

```
$.ajax({   
   url: url,   
   dataType: 'json',   
   async: true,   
   data: myData,   
   success: function(data) {     // loadSavedItem();   } 
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: That is what he's doing - `getJSON` only runs the function when the data is returned.

Comment: Yeh, the return of getJSON is not the problem, it's waiting for the `$(each..` to finish... I think @Grim 's idea is the answer. I'll try...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the clue is `async` setting for `jQuery.ajax()`.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Changing async to false won't help in this case (it won't run the code until the server has responded), and is a really bad idea in general - if the server doesn't respond it freezes the user's browser.